# 2D array C to MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I am trying to convert the following C function to MIPS but I cannot figure out how to translate the 2D array part of it.

```
    int distance(unsigned arr[15][15],
                          int coord[2], unsigned target) {
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++ i) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 15 ; ++ j) {
          if (arr[i][j] == target) {
            return ((i - coord[0]) * (i - coord[0]) +
                    (j - coord[1]) * (j - coord[1]));
       } 
    }

  }
    return -1; 
}
```

So far all I have is the double for loop in MIPS but it would be great if someone could assist on how I could do the if and return statements.

```
distance:
    li $t0, 0 # i
    li $t1, 0 # j

    loop_one:
        bge $t0, 15, loop_one_done
        loop_two:
            bge $t1, 15, loop_two_done

            addi $t1, $t1, 1
            j loop_two
        loop_two_done:
            addi $t0, $t0, 1
            j loop_one
    loop_one_done:

    jr  $ra
```

Comment: You have to remember that in C when you pass an array to a function, it decays to a *pointer* to its first element. And the compiler when translating array arguments translates it as a pointer not an array. That means your argument `unsigned arr[15][15]` is really `unsigned (*arr)[15]`. So all you have, really, is a *pointer* and not an array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So when I have a one dimensional array being passed through like int *array I can access it using mul and add to move every 4 bits but I don't know how to do the translation with a 2d array. How could I go about doing this? Also, I am an assembly/MIPS beginner so all of this is pretty new to me.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/RW2ixj

Comment: You have to remember that a "2d" array is really an array *of arrays*. For a "normal" array you have `a[0]` directly followed by `a[1]` etc., right? But if `a[0]` is an array it's nothing different. I suggest you draw out a small "2d" array (like e.g. `int arr[3][2]`) on a piece of paper, and try to figure out a pattern to access a member of each sub-array (hint: It's one multiplication and a total of two additions). Of, and it probably helps if if you understand that for any array `arr` and index `i`, the expression `arr[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(arr + i)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is helpful thank you for that explanation.